# Is the excuted instruction stream always the same when Linux boots?

Tags: linux-kernel

For the same computer, when the Linux operating system boots, is the executed instruction stream always the same? I guess it might be but I am not sure. Any help will be welcome!

Cheers,

Comment: Of course not. Even on UP systems it may deviate.

Comment: What causes the difference? When the system boots, the boot loader launches the OS into memory and then transfers the execution to the OS. The OS will create different processes. Where does it have a different instruction stream?

Comment: Depending how deep you want to dive. The law of thermodynamics defines that.

Comment: The only **simple one thread** code on an **interrupt-less**  microcontroller runs the same, as being a state machine.